# How to find and install wifi driver for Realtek RTL8111 for HP laptop for ubuntu

Tags: drivers, wireless, realtek

I am unable to use Built-In wifi adapter of Realtek RTL8111 in recently installed Ubuntu. I found Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller in my laptop.

Please help me, i am new in Linux Ecosystem. 
The Output of
amit-ubuntu@amitubuntu-HP-Laptop-15-bs0xx:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319]
amit-ubuntu@amitubuntu-HP-Laptop-15-bs0xx:~$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

Comment: RTL8111 is an Ethernet controller, not WiFi.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless.html.en  (it's a page of options, which include can't see, troubleshooter & more)

Comment: I have HP laptop and it has inbuld wifi which was working truly fine with windows 10. But now it not working at all after installing Ubuntu on the same machine. Please tell me how i can use wifi in ubuntu . I tried a lot by following previous available solutions but did not work.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal commands: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and also: `rfkill list all`. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: result of the terminal commands: lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3 and also: rfkill list all are as below: -                                                                                                          amit-ubuntu@amitubuntu-HP-Laptop-15-bs0xx:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319]
amit-ubuntu@amitubuntu-HP-Laptop-15-bs0xx:~$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no